# What the products are not added in the product list?(supermarket.cpp)

Tags: c++

I can only change functions that says need to implement. The products are not being added to the list, Why? (Also please take a look at the read/display list of product function)  (supermarket.cpp)

The product is another class which has variable such quantiry, price and such.
The supermarket system maintains a list of products that an administrator add an product and read products.

At supermarket.cpp

```
{
Add_new_product_in_productlist(p3); //p3 is product type object    
list<Product> Plist=GetProduct_list(); //Return the prolist from supermarket
Write_product_in_supermarket_system(Plist);
Read_products_from_supermarket_system();
void Supermarket::Write_product_in_supermarket_system(list
}

list <Product> product_list)
{
     SetProduct_list(product_list);
     cout <<"StProduct Count in ADD_new"<<GetTotalProductsCount()<<endl;
}  

  //Read display the product from product list
  list<Product> Supermarket::Read_products_from_supermarket_system()
  {
    list<Product> Productlist = GetProduct_list();
    list<Product>:: iterator iterator;

    for(iterator = Productlist.begin(); 
         iterator != Productlist.end();++iterator)      {
    iterator->Display_Product();
    cout <<"I am here"<<endl;

    return Productlist;
  }
```

Comment: Please debug my program. No.

Comment: @Mukul - You *are* asking us to debug your code.  You want us to take your code, compile it, run it, **debug it**, and give you an answer.  Why not learn to use the debugger that comes with your compiler tool suite?

Comment: *can you guys take a look at the code*  -- You have a mountain of code.  No programmer can take all that code and ingest it at one time.  You could have reduced this down to a small, reproducible example using `std::list` and references.

Comment: okay, it was actually bad(there were a mountain of code), i kind of panicked, sorry guys.

Comment: @Mukul [As an example](http://ideone.com/8vgiVM)  Note that the list is empty.  Why is it empty?  You could have experimented with something like the example to see that you need to return a reference, not a copy of the list.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it is not empty, i have added several products to the list, and i am calling the function (after pushing back product into the list) that returns the number of products. That's why i know, that products are not being added to the list.

Comment: @Mukul I don't understand what you're saying.  You say you're adding products to the list, and then you discovered that products are not being added to the list.  Second, your code that returned an object instead of a reference, and then assigned that to a reference is invalid C++.  Third, the answer you accepted illustrates exactly what the problem is, and the small example program [could have been adjusted](http://ideone.com/uNizuT) to show this:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is from the combination of this couple of methods

```
list<Product> Supermarket::GetProduct_list()
 {return Product_list;}

void Supermarket::Add_new_product_in_productlist(Product P)
{
   //Need to Implement
   list<Product>& Product_list = GetProduct_list();
   Product_list.push_back(P);
   cout <<"GetProduct Count in ADD_new"<<GetTotalProductsCount()<<endl;
}
```

`GetProduct_list()` return a **copy** of the member `Product_list`, so when you define

```
   list<Product>& Product_list = GetProduct_list();
```

you obtain a reference to a **copy** of the member; when you add a product

```
   Product_list.push_back(P);
```

you add a product in a copy of the member, not in the member. Copy that is destroyer exiting from `Add_new_product_in_productlist()`

I suppose you could simply avoid the use of `GetProduct_list()`

```
void Supermarket::Add_new_product_in_productlist(Product P)
{
   Product_list.push_back(P);
   cout <<"GetProduct Count in ADD_new"<<GetTotalProductsCount()<<endl;
}
```

but, if you want use `GetProduct_list()` in this way, you should return a reference to `Product_list`, so

```
list<Product> & Supermarket::GetProduct_list()
 { return Product_list; }
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English

Comment: `list<Product>& Product_list = GetProduct_list();` -- This shouldn't compile if `GetProduce_list()` returns an object and not a reference.